# Update ItemsControl.ItemsSource based on selected object of a another ItemsControl

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui, dynamic-data

We use ReactiveUI and DynamicData and have two ListBoxes: **ListBoxA** and **ListBoxB**. Based on the selection of **ListBoxA**, the list in **ListBoxB** should be updated (Not filtered). Seems straightforward but I am having some trouble refreshing **ListBoxB**

The ListBoxes are bound like so in the View:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ItemsA, v => v.ListBoxA.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);    
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedItemA, v => v.ListBoxA.SelectedItem).DisposeWith(disposables);    
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ItemsB, v => v.ListBoxB.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

ViewModel:=

```
_storage.PoolA.Connect()
                .Transform(m => new ViewModelForA(m))
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out _itemsA)
                .Subscribe();

SelectedItemA.PoolB.Connect()
                 .Transform(c => new ViewModelForB(c))
                 .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                 .Bind(out _itemsB)
                 .Subscribe();
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you select something in `ListBoxA` your `SelectedItemA` object changes and you need to recreate you connection to it.

At first we create an IObservable from SelectedItemA and then use Switch operator from DynamicData

```
class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChange
{
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    _storage.PoolA.Connect()
    ...

    this.WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.SelectedItemA)
      .Select(x => x.Value.PoolB)
      .Switch() // Switch from DynamicData
      .Transform(c => new ViewModelForB(c))
      .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
      .Bind(out _itemsB)
      .Subscribe();
  }

}
```